# JHipster - import-jdl - Field has jhi_ added to name

Tags: java, mysql, jhipster, jdl

I've created a new JHipster project, used JDL Studio to create a .jh schema file, and added it to the project. After doing the import-jdl and project rebuild, one of my fields has had 'jhi_' added to the name.

Can anyone shed light on this? 
I'm guessing maybe I've used a reserved word. But I can't find a list of JHipster's reserved words, if there are any.

Thanks in advance.

Full details:

JHipster generation options: monolithic, not using Registry, JWT authentication, MySQL database, Hazelcast cache implementation, 2nd level cache enabled, Gradle, WebSockets, Angular, SASS, no internationalisation, Protractor, no other generators.

The field affected is the *cost* field in this JDL definition:

```
entity Product {
    description String required maxlength(100)
    price BigDecimal required min(0)
    cost BigDecimal required min(0)
    weight Integer min(0)
    barcode String required maxlength(13)
    shelfLife Integer min(0)
    isActive Boolean required
    lastModified Instant required
}
```

And its relationships:

```
relationship OneToMany {
   Product to Shelf{product (description) required},
   Product to TransactionItem{product (description) required}
```

}

It appears in the MySQL database, and in all generated code, as *jhi_cost*

All other fields are appearing exactly as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COST is listed as a reserved word for Oracle in the generator (see [oracle.js](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/master/lib/core/jhipster/reserved_keywords/oracle.js)) so it gets prefixed when you select Oracle as target database. The prefix is globally configurable using `--jhi-prefix` command line option. You say you use MySQL so it's a bit surprising as COST is not included in [mysql.js](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/master/lib/core/jhipster/reserved_keywords/mysql.js) so maybe there's a bug you should report on github with your project setup.